# How do you center floated element that overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a large amount of floated elements inside of a container with an overflow setting of auto.  These elements (depending on screen-size) will almost always overflow to the next line as they should, however, I want to be able to center the parent div so these elements will always be centered in the page.  The container is 100% of the screen width.

Oh, and to make things interesting: the size of the floated elements... is subject to change.

[Here's what I'm referring to.](http://photopicker.goldenspiralcreative.com/?album=Kylie%20Rae%20Harris)

There's a lot of great solutions out there that I've found that have to deal with a single row of floated elements, but I'm almost never going to be dealing with that few items.  I will overflow to the next line practically every time, which is why those methods don't work.

Would I be best inserting clear divs every few elements, setting the width and centering the container, or is there a better way to do this without Javascript?  Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Could you just center all of the elements?  Wouldn't that in turn end up centering the elements that overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to fix this with CSS. Put a width on your container div, and add a `margin: 0 auto;` to it. I found on your page it works well with a width of 1000px. The problem is if you use a width of 100%, you can't control how many of your floating divs will fit in one row, and when it will wrap because you don't know the viwer's window size. If you set a fixed width you have control over how many boxes will fit in each row.

Comment: I decided to go with a fixed width solution.  The only way I could think of doing it without is by using some pretty heavy javascript.  For me, it's not an important enough feature to spend time on such a thing.